# How do I trigger a function after the user has had his mouse over an element for x seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

Here's my code:

```
$('#element').hover(function()
{
    window.setTimeout(function()
    {
        alert('hovered for 2 seconds');
    }, 2000);
},
function()
{
    alert('mouse left');
});
```

But it doesn't quite work the way I want it to.

What I'm actually trying to do is, if the user has his mouse over the `#element` for **2 seconds** it should trigger the `alert()`. But if he moves his mouse away from the `#element` **before the 2 seconds are over** nothing should happen.

And the problem with the current code is that if I move my mouse over the `#element` and move it away before the 2 secs are over, it still triggers the `alert()` after 2 secs.

I really hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there. You need to store the result of `setTimeout` (I used jQuery's data), then call `clearTimeout` with the same value.

```
$('#element').hover(function()
{
    $(this).data('timeout', window.setTimeout(function()
    {
        alert('hovered for 2 seconds');
    }, 2000));
},
function()
{
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
    alert('mouse left');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nCcxt/

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks so much, Daniel!